# How to upload my own model to Azure and deploy it?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-storage

I create and trained my model locally. Now I want to deploy it to Azure. How to do it?
I created Azure Storage Account and read about Azure Functions.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really broad but this should get you started: [Deploy models with Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=azcli)